# How to make height of a QPushButton automatically fit the text?

Tags: qt, qpushbutton

I have a QPushButton

```
QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton();
btn->setText("Push \n Button");
```

The result is:

[image]

I have tried `btn->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Preferred)` with Qt Designer but it does not help.
[image]

How can do so that the height of the button is automatically adjusted to fit with the content when I call `setText`?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the vertical [size policy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setSizePolicy-1) to an option that allows the widget to grow, the default option for vertical size policy of `QPushButton` is fixed, you can do it like this from code:

```
btn->setText("Push \n Button");
btn->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
```

You can change it in designer, if you use that to create your ui.
See more options in the documentation [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum) and choose the one that best suits your needs.

Also use layouts for your widgets, those help a lot, especially if your windows can change size.

Comment: thanks for your help. I have tried with Qt Designer, but it does not work. I still do not see the result after setting like that. I have updated result above.

Comment: Well first put it in a layout, if you don't you are in full control of the size it has (so you'll need to manually make it bigger). And second you set the size policy for the widget, not the button (or at least that is what you show us), so select the button and set the size policy for it.

Comment: thanks for your enthusiasm :). I set size policy for the button not the widget, i updated the pictured above. I think the problem here is set the button in a layout. When I do it, it works as expected. But the problem here is I want to build the standalone widget, that means whether we set it in a layout or not, the size is automatically adjusted. Do you have another possible solution?

Comment: When you are not putting it into a layout Qt won't automatically adjust anything, layouts are part of Qt, you should not try to avoid it.